# C library can't find it's .cfg file on iOS

Tags: swift, xcode, dylib

I have compiled the labstreaminglayer library for an iOS app, which works fine. But I would like to  do some configuration as described [here](https://labstreaminglayer.readthedocs.io/info/lslapicfg.html). But I can't get the library to find the lsl_api.cfg file.

Just putting it in any of the folders in XCode doesn't work, even though I can see that **is** there by searching for it and printing the path. I can set the LSLAPICFG environment variable but again anything I can think to put in there for a relative path doesn't point to the right place and I can't find any other env variable in [this](https://gist.github.com/ben-xD/c063b0ca2c33684de1eb379bb9d6405d) list which gives the absolute path...

Comment: Well you obviously can't use the global or per-user config file, for `$PWD` you need to check what the working directory of your app actually is at launch, and for `LSLAPICFG` you'll have to check at what point the variable is checked. If it's checked from a static initialiser, then then you may be setting the variable too late.

Answer (score 0):

With the benefit of a nights sleep I realised I can just edit liblsl and add some logging to figure out what is going on. So liblsl tries to look for the config file in the ~ folder, giving the path:

```
/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/GUID1/
```

While the lsl_api.cfg file is copied to:

```
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/GUID2/APPNAME.app/lsl_api.cfg
```

And libsl can't seem to access files in the GUID2 folder at all, something to do with sandboxing perhaps?

But both liblsl and the App can *both* access the /Documents folder (perhaps because I enabled iTunes File Sharing?) so I can just chuck the cfg file in there and update libsl to find it. With the added benefit that I can just edit it on my mac.

So I'm still not sure what I would do if I didn't want to put the cfg file in the /Documents folder but at least this works!

Comment: It can't be down to sandboxing because all your code runs in the same process. If the library tries to open the file for writing, then that will certainly fail though, since things in `/private/var/containers` are owned by a separate user, by design so apps cannot modify themselves.